# how to get imageview outside the scope of Onitemclicklistener

Tags: android

How can I get ImageView outside the scope of OnItemClickListener?

```
mListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);
            if (switches==true) {
                imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                preferences.edit().putBoolean("tgpref", true).commit();
                switches = false;
            } else {
                imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                preferences.edit().putBoolean("tgpref", false).commit();
                switches = true;
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: Write your code `imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);` above the this `OnItemClickListener()` or in `OnCreate()`

Comment: its not working because imageview is not from R.layout.activity_main
its from another xml file which is R.layout.activity_row
so how can i get image view to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `inflater` in `onCreate...You'll have to add the ImageView to the current layout using addView().

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null); //activity_row.xml is your file.
imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the

```
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);
```

outside-before the scope of the onItemClickListener.

In other words, put it on the scope of the hole class-activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);

String[] itemname = { "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth", "Mobile Data", };
Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, };
ImageView mListView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAppList1);
preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
finalRowActivityadapter=newRowActivity(this,itemname,imgid); 
mListView2.setAdapter(adapter); 
mListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
    //here you can now access imageView2
}
```

Comment: After putting on create , java null exception occurs

Comment: can you please copy all your class?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] itemname = { "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth", "Mobile Data",

  };
Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
};mListView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAppList1);
  preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
 finalRowActivityadapter=newRowActivity(this,itemname,imgid);
  mListView2.setAdapter(adapter);
  mListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);

Comment: now i am posting my complete code having two activities hope so u got it and ans me

Comment: it is also not working because imageview is from another xml file??
not from R.layout.activity_main
sol??

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, as R gets it by its id, it's its id "applist_item_image" correct?

Comment: yeah you are right 
but em googling all day but not getting answer yet

Comment: can you please post your hole activity somewhere? as i don't understand where you problem can be

Answer (score 0):

You can declare imageview global like:- ImageView imageview

Comment: i did it but java null exception cause find by id is in onitemclicklistener i want to use that imageview outside onitemclicklistener scope ..??
how???

Comment: if you do the same you can easily use outside the imageview

Comment: i did it by declaring global but null exception occurs..what i should do now?

Comment: after declaring you can also initialize imageview in onClickListerner like:- imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageidname);

Comment: its not working because imageview is not from R.layout.activity_main its from another xml file which is R.layout.activity_row so how can i get image view to solve my problem?

Comment: try this imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image); and declare imageview2 is global